# How to add a new field with initial value to django queryset result?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have a queryset like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 5}, {'id': 4}]>
```

and I want to add new field `n` to it with initial value `0`.

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 5, 'n': 0}, {'id': 4, 'n': 0}]]>
```

This is my code so far:

```
drivers_not_in_rides = Driver.objects.all().filter(
        car__ride__in=ride_ids_with_conditions
).values('id').annotate(
    n=0
)
```

But I get this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

Can anyone give me some advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) like so:

```py
from django.db.models import Value

drivers_not_in_rides = Driver.objects.all().filter(
    car__ride__in=ride_ids_with_conditions
).values('id').annotate(
    n=Value(0, output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

Comment: and also ```output_field=IntegerField()```

Comment: Thanks, @AliAbbasifard. I've edited the post to add that.